# When trying to rid my app of the title bar, my app crashes

Tags: android, crash, themes, titlebar

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="uk.co.willmudgelive.ketimer">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I'm referring to `android:theme`, I checked through multiple websites trying to find out how to do this and it looks like this is what I need to do, but it isn't working. Any help is appreciated.

As per request, log:

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: uk.co.willmudgelive.ketimer, PID: 21308
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{uk.co.willmudgelive.ketimer/uk.co.willmudgelive.ketimer.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:347)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:316)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:281)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                      at uk.co.willmudgelive.ketimer.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:221) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1794) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21308 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8602', transport: 'socket'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do not want to show title and action bar as well then you can write 
inside your onCreate() method 
getSupportActionBar().hide()